# How to restart the tomcat server in redhat centos 7?

Tags: reactjs

What is the command to restart the tomcat server?

Comment: Its not matter of react, its matter of your host server (apache, nginx). You must specify it there somewhat. If you want to run https on development environment have a look there https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/

Comment: Whether it is possible to host it in the node server?

Comment: sh shutdown.sh  { Command will down the server. }

Comment: ps -ef | grep tomcat  { used to see the logs or process were stopped or not. } ,                  sh startup.sh  { command will up the server. }

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the putty in the centos 7
2. Change the directory into the tomcat bin folder.
3. Run the below commands.
4. Command will shut down the server: `sh shutdown.sh`
5. To see the logs or process were stopped or not: `ps -ef | grep tomcat`
6. Command will boot the server: `sh startup.sh`
7. Hence tomcat server will be restarted